# Is there a term for the top-most parent class where a specific method is introduced in OOP? (Root class?)

Tags: oop, inheritance, conventions

Is there a term for the top-most parent class in OOP where some specific method (e.g. newMethod as per the diagram below) is introduced?

Every intro, walk-through, wiki page, or example hierarchy diagram I looked through seems to be lacking the term.

[image]

[UML Generator](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/bP2n2i9038RtF4Nef4E7Fe451wSMSN4ElS09Pm9tEQI8xwuUbGDrq2ty-RwVa3uPHSld0AB6s1mz6Jh5MJDE50AQFoMS0gMqQP0IZXt0GTMmRN4NIToU8ej1dSjgIMimpDjd2OpTkrboB9rNo18vaB4RsBowrHfk2r2LxvpmvSFv3t_T-0FVixZ7q-u0)

Maybe in languages like Java where there can only be one parent this could be easier to define, but what about other languages that allow for multiple parents? Would such a term be a moot effort to try to define in this case?